# Is a predicate with variable arity acceptable in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

Is it possible to have a "variable arity predicate" in Prolog?

I mean something like this:

```
my_predicate( [a,b,c], [a,c], [a], [a,b,c,d], N, RESULT)
```

with the number of initial lists unknown at the beginning?

Using the `univ` operator ( =.. ) it would be possible to unify it with a list of terms and traversing it like every other list. But how to write the goal?

```
my_predicate(??) =.. [??]
```

I really don't know if this is even possible..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can define predicates with different arities that have the same name but they will be different predicates.

```
foo(1).
foo(2,1).

?-foo(2).
false
```

my suggestion is to change the encoding; instead of a number of initial lists, have a list of initial lists.
the other solution would be to write predicates for all the possible numbers of arguments (or dynamically generate them).

Comment: I thought of it, and it seems more reasonable to me.. but I didn't write the directive.

Comment: I think the text is wrong.. it literally says "Let's have a predicate with a list of lists at the first parameter...". I guess the predicate's text I wrote above is completely wrong. Probably the writer did a mistake

Answer (score 4):

As @thanosQR suggests, it probably is the best to change your representation to some list.

There are, however - very seldom but nevertheless - situations where you want to define a predicate for many different arities. In this very rare case, you can define such a predicate manually. That is, for each arity manually. Of course, you will only define several cases. As an example, see [library(lambda)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl).

Answer (score 3):

You always can go up to one level :) Many years ago I saw implementation of ANSI prolog interpter in Turbo Prolog. Idea was very simple, enclose all user-space facts and rules in single fact backed by assert/retract-like operations.

Consider enclosing all your targets in another compose:

```prolog
target(my_predicate( [a,b,c], [a,c], [a], [a,b,c,d], N, RESULT)) :- RESULT=[a], N=1.
target(H) :- H =.. [my_predicate|_].
target(using_my_predicate(X, Y)) :- target(my_predicate(X,1,Y)).
```

Some prologs (at least YAP) have directives to declare handlers for unknown targets:

```
:- module(sumtest).

target(sum(0)).
target(H) :-
    H =.. [sum, S, X|XS],
    H1 =.. [sum, S1|XS],
    H1,
    S is (S1+X).

target(sumtest:G):- target(G). % HACK: strip-off module

:- unknown(_, target(_)).

test:-
    sum(X,1), write(X), nl,
    sum(Y,2,3), write(Y), nl,
    sum(Z,3,4,2), write(Z), nl,
    target(sum(X1,1)), write(X1), nl,
    target(sum(Y1,2,3)), write(Y1), nl,
    target(sum(Z1,3,4,2)), write(Z1), nl.


:- test, halt.
% % yap -l sumtest.pl
% YAP 6.2.0 (amd64): Thu Oct 21 10:31:27 EEST 2010
% MYDDAS version MYDDAS-0.9.1
% 1
% 5
% 9
% 1
% 5
% 9
%  % YAP execution halted
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, although it's out of my possibilities for now :)

Comment: There is two ways of using that solutions. One is using directive to specify handler for unknown targets. And other is always wrap head of target in additional layer (`target(sum(X))` insted of just `sum(X)`).